# can we assem a Controller to a node in JavaFx2?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

i do something such like this :
define a tablecell extends TableCell , i define a FXML(FXML-b) to design the UI of this tablecell.

```
    class TableCell4Operater<T0, T1> extends TableCell<T0, T1> {
    .....
    public TableCell4Operater(){
    URL url = getClass().getResource("operpan.fxml");  // FXML-b
        FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlloader.setLocation(url);
        fxmlloader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        try {
            node = (Node) fxmlloader.load(url.openStream());
                        *// here i get the Controller from the FXML definded*
            this.controller = (OperpanController) fxmlloader.getController();
                 }
}
}
```

in the class i can get the Node and the controller , 
but i need to define the controller method in this TableCell class , 
as i need controlling the event of some object such as a button's onAction() event ,
and i also need to post event up to the "main stage" who create the table that this tableCell belong ,

all things to do is just to make the target :
when i click a button from the table's cell (defined above) on the "main stage",
i can change something such as a TextField's text on the "main stage",

so the road of Event transfer is :
Button in Table cell(FXML-b) -> Table on "main stage"(FXML-a) -> "main stage"(FXML-a)

can anybody teach me how to how to achieve, thanks a lot!

Comment: why you does not make a function in fxml-a-controller that is public and call it in the button_clicked function in fxml-b-controller

Comment: But is it really a change of state, when the button is pressed.  This can be expressed by a property on the controller, bound to one property per table cell.

Comment: To Kalaschni : thank you first . but how to do this, the button is on the other fxml, i just cannot quote the button in the "TableCell" , because the "TableCell"(TableCell4Operater) is definded as a standard along class , it is not the inner class in Controller-A.

Comment: To Kalaschni: as following your suggestion, i put the "TableCell" extend class in Controller-A as inner class , and i need modify the instance of Controller-B of FXML-B - to change the button's click action function like this :     controller.getBtn1().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
     
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      // TODO 
      txttip.setText("haha");
     }
    }); -- is there any other way elegance.